What is the best strategy?
The scenario is I am having a utility function $u(w)=\ln w$. Suppose further I have a
net worth of $100$ and I am offered a game of two turns: each turn is a gamble
that I have a chance of winning (same for both turns). If I win a gamble
I get a payoff $3$ for each bitcoin I bet on that turn (i.e. I get back how much I bet plus
two more). If I lose I get nothing, i.e. I don't get my bet back. What strategy
can I follow to maximize my expected utility after two turns?
My idea is to maximize my expected utility turn by turn:
Let $w$ be my current wealth and $x$ be the bet. Then the expected utility is
$$
E(U(x))=p\ln (w+2x) + (1-p)\ln (w-x)
$$
Solve $\dfrac{dE(U(x))}{dx}=0$ to find the optimal $x$:
$$
\frac{2p}{w+2x}-\frac{1-p}{w-x}=0\Longrightarrow
x=\frac{(3p-1)w}{2}
$$
So at each turn, I will bet $x=\dfrac{(3p-1)w}{2}$ to maximize my outcome.
I think there are better strategies. Can anyone help?

"you get a payoff 3 for each bitcoin you bet" would be $w - x + 3x = w + 2x$. You might also notice something is wrong by trying $p=\frac 12$, and your formula would advise you to bet $-1$.

Thank you. I have adjsuted the post. Is the strategy correct now?

Draw a probability tree, you'll end up with four nodes after two gambles: {(w,w), (w,l), (l,w), (l,l)}, where w = win and l = lose. Maximize the expected value over those four possibilities. That also allows you to take into account different probabilities for the second gamble in case they depend on the outcome of the first gamble.

This is a straight Kelly Criterion question.
Recall the Kelly formula for what fraction, $f$ of your wealth to bet is:
$$f = p - \frac{1-p}{B}$$
Where $B$ is the win/loss ratio, and $p$ is the probability of success. In your example, you said that you net a total win of 2 times the amount that you risk so $B$ would be $2$ in this case. Given that you want $x$ to represent your bet and $w$ to be your wealth at that instant in time, we get:
$$x = w \left( p - \frac{1 - p}{2} \right)$$
This is equivalent to the final equation that you arrived at on your own.
